# Java process executor in Mac OS

Tags: java, windows, macos, process

I am using the below code to close all the FireFox instances in a windows machine. Can this same code used in Mac machine? If not what will be the best approach?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM FireFox.exe");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can this same code used in Mac machine?

Nope.

But this will work:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pgrep 'firefox' | xargs kill");
```

Explanation of `pgrep 'firefox' | xargs kill`

> **pgrep 'firefox'** - find all process ids that match processes having firefox in their name.
>
> **| xargs kill** - Pass all the process IDs found from pgrep as input to the kill command.

Comment: Thanks. It helped. :)